# How do I make this code to validate user input?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, c99

So here's my code snippet (assume that the variables are declared as type int):

```
    printf("number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &y;


    int sample_arr[x][y];

 
    printf("\nEnter elements of the array:\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++){
        printf("Row %d: ", i+1);
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++){
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
```

Code output:

number of rows: 3
number of columns: 5

enter elements of the array:
Row 1: 1 2 3
// prints a blank space here but can still receive user input

Expected output:
number of rows: 3
number of columns: 5

Row 1: 1 2 3
Please make sure that the elements you have entered corresponds with the number of column to form a matrix!

(Asks the user again)
Row 1: 1 2 3 4 5
................
Row 5: 1 2 3 4 5

I'm not really sure on what to do.

Comment: Reading and understanding the value of the return result of [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Input validation with `scanf` is nearly impossible. Don't try it, it will only end in tears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the result from *scanf* which returns the number of successfully matched and assigned input items (integers in this case). Here is a complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ReadInteger(int *result)
{
    int n = scanf("%d", result);
    if (n != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "integer expected\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


void ReadPositiveInteger(int *result)
{
    ReadInteger(result);
    if (*result <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "positive integer expected\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    // read array
    int x, y;
    printf("number of rows: ");
    ReadPositiveInteger(&x);
    printf("number of columns: ");
    ReadPositiveInteger(&y);    
    int sample_arr[x][y];
    printf("\nEnter elements of the array:\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        printf("Row %d: ", i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            ReadInteger(&sample_arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // print array
    printf("\nHere is the array:\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            printf("%d ", sample_arr[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example input/output:

```
number of rows: 2
number of columns: 3

Enter elements of the array:

Row 1: 1 2 3
Row 2: 3 4 5

Here is the array:

1 2 3 
3 4 5
```